# Angular state provider not displaying full URL

Tags: angularjs

I just inherited an application where there are several `ui-sref="portal.main.content"` in the code.

What I'm confused about is, to navigate to this state, we need to enter /#/portal/main/content.

However it is rendered on the page without the `#`.  So it will work when clicking on the page, however it won't work if I try to open into a new tab as that page doesn't exist.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that your application is served from a server environment that deals with urls as if they were real paths for real resources on the server file system. Therefore, when your are in a single page, it's not reloaded when you navigate to another state url, because `ui-router` handle this internally, consequently doesn't produce `404` or `403` errors, but when you load a page first time, it's required from the server and gives you `404` and `403` errors because the resource you're looking for doesn't exists or is forbidden.

What you have to do is to configure your server side environment to target the `index.html` page when your are not refering to a file (like css and js files), so all url will end up in the `index.html` page with an url to be handled by the ui-router. Each server side technology (Apache, IIS, node.js, etc) will have a different way to handle this, but mostly have a URL Rewrite module and similar ways to handle this.

Also, if it's not a problem by using the hash like url, you can disable `html5Mode` to prevent `ui-router` to do such thing. You can achieve this by injecting `$locationProvider` on your `.config` and disabling it like so: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`

For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '',
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            })
            .state('about', {
                url: '/about',
                templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
                controller: 'aboutCtrl'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    });
```

Comment: Correct.  So how do I have it rendered so the hash is a part of the URL when using ui-sref.  If I manually enter the URL with the hash, it works fine.

Comment: @KingKongFrog answering your question in the previous comment, I've updated my answer.